# Django NoReverseMatch at /display/

Tags: django

I'm working on a simple app where pet users can create boards about their pets and display pictures on the boards.

I'm trying to create a feature where users can click on their boards which will redirect them into their boards which will display all their pets pictures .

[image]

*I get an error when I try to configure my template to redirect the users to their boards.*

```
Reverse for 'Boat' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
Django Version: 1.4.3 
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch 
Exception Value: Reverse for 'Boat' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 

Error during template rendering
In template C:\o\mysite\pet\templates\edit.html, error at line 14
13     {% for b in board %}         

14     <li><a href ="{% url world:Boat animal.id %}">{{ b.name }}</li>
```

[image]

*I think problem is right here
When the user clicks on a board . My URLconf will capture the animal.id and pass it into my Boat function but I'm not sure what went wrong*

```
<li><a href ="{% url world:Boat animal.id %}">{{ b.name }}</li>
```

**My edit.html**

```
<h4>My Boards</h4>
{% if board %} 
<ul>  
    {% for b in board %}         
    <li><a href ="{% url world:Boat animal.id %}">{{ b.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

**My Main URLconf**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(
        r'^admin/', 
        include(admin.site.urls)
    ),
    url(
        r'^',
        include('pet.urls',
            namespace = 'world')
    ),
```

**Parts of my Pet app URLconf**

```
url(
    r'^(?P<animal_id>\d+)/$',
    'pet.views.Boat',
    name = 'Boat',
),
```

**My parts of my views.py**

```
def Profile(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)
            person.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            person.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            person.save() 
    return render(request,'profile.html',{'form': PersonForm()})

def Boat(request ,animal_id):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))

    picture = Picture.objects.filter(board=animal_id)
    return render(request,'boat.html',{'picture':picture})
```

Thank you for helping me :]

My more of my views.py

```
def Display(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))
    board = Board.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'edit.html',{'board':board ,'person':person})
```

My models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers', symmetrical=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Board(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Are you sure that in this line `{% url world:Boat animal.id %}`, `animal.id` has a value? It seems that the reverse cannot find the argument for the url.

Comment: Also, you are using a named argument on your url conf but passing a positional argument on the call to the `url` tag on the template.

Comment: Can I see your board models?

Comment: you are now #2 in top django askers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have value for animal.id

```
{% if board %} 
<ul>  
    {% for b in board %}         
    <li><a href ="{% url world:Boat b.id %}">{{ b.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that, within your template, the value `animal.id` isn't resolving.

Because the variable is empty, your URL regex `^(?P<animal_id>\d+)/$` won't match. The regex specifies a digit, and you're passing in an empty string.

As for why it's not resolving, we'd need to see the view which is rendering 'edit.html'.

Comment: How could I make animal.id into a digit and pass into my URL regex?

Comment: It looks like 'animal' is a board? So swap {%url world:Boat animal.id %} with {% url world:Boat board.id %}

Comment: Okay I done that. I still get the error but I don't think swaping board.id with animal.id does something

Comment: You need to sort out what the name of the variable you're passing to your template is. The issue is that, for whatever reason, the variable you're calling in your template either does not exist, or does not have an id value.

Comment: Can you give me an example.I'm bit lost on how you can sort out the name of variable